Identifying martial arts movie (possibly with bodybuilders)
I'm trying to find an asian (I think) movie that I watched when I was a kid back in the 90's. The movie itself may be from the late 70's -80s. It had some crazy fights in mid air and what-not, it was a very cheesy movie.
All I remember was one average guy that was trying his best to get into a martial arts school, where he worked as a janitor. Their members (the good guys) looked very strong, possibly bodybuilders (or at least that's how I recall it). They used to practice all kinds of exercises to become more powerful. The sensei of the school would not accept the main actor into his school at the beginning, but after a while he got persuaded into it. 
At the beginning of his training he was very weak (I think I remember the sensei touching our guy's flabby abs), but after a while he became very powerful.
In the end he was strong enough to fight the bad guy (might be someone's son from a rival martial arts school) and defeat him.
I don't remember what the main plot of the movie was, this is all I remember.

Some stark similarities between this movie and Karate Kid (though I assume you've already ruled that out): Mr. Miyagi was a janitor; main character started out weak who became strong; defeat of bad guy from rival martial arts school. Though these are probably all fairly common in martial arts movies.

Nope, it`s not Karate Kid. Ive watched that many times. Anyways thanks for trying guys but it looks like i'm doomed never to find this one, haha  >:]

It's neither Drunken Master. It looked like one of those "cheap" asian flicks that were poping in that era like mushrooms after the rain, and like i said these guys were doing some supernatural fights, cheesy stuff.

There is a close to sure way to rule out if it's western or eastern. If you were reading subtitles or hearing really bad dubs then it's most likely Eastern. Also the music tends to be significantly different

Also many cheesy films from the east tend to have the much of the same actors

Is there any response to the answers below?

This is the movie, it's called Operation Scorpio / Scorpion King.




Welcome to Movies and TV Beta! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

That is the movie, Gogulet! Wooot, thank you so much! :)

Shaolin Master Killer also titled The 36th Chamber of Shaolin
Pretty close to the plot minus the mid-air fights.

+1 Hah, completely forgot about that. Fits in much more ways than my answer.

+1 This was the one I was pegging as the answer, just couldn't for the life of me remember the title.

Shaolin Master Killer looks close to what i was looking for but it ain't it :)

I also just remembered these days when i thought more of the movie that the sensei was not an old guy, he was the strongest one out of his school with a well built body. I played a bit of Sherlock Holmes these days and tried google-ing all sorts of things to find this movie. Bolo Yeung would be a close look to the sensei but he wasn't in this movie. Also gaved up on looking it up after finding a kung-fu movie fanatic that told me there are about +5000 movies from that era. Props to Christian for talking like that about Jean M. Jarre's music :P

I'm not really sure and many things don't match, but the part of the main character being the janitor of the martial arts school reminds me of Snake in the Eagle's Shadow, an early Jackie Chan movie I watched quite often many years ago, with a great synthesizer soundtrack (featuring works from Jean-Michel Jarre and Space).
But in this movie the martial arts students aren't really good guys and they bully him all the time until he gets trained by some old wise guy. I also don't think there was any supernatural stuff in it, but with all this synthesizer music and sound effects (and some over the top cinematography), one could really get the impression of supernaturality, especially as a kid.

American Shaolin? A movie about an American guy who tries to join a Shaolin temple in China, to become a monk and learn about kungfu. These guys aren't bodybuilders here but your description sounds similar in some aspects.

I don't know if you already found the name of the movie that you looking for, but just in case that you didn't, here is the name of the movie: Shaolin Kickboxer from 1992. here is also the link for more info. https://ssl.ofdb.de/film/3948,Shaolin-Kickboxer.
